# How to set google map padding on map fragment on android? and also I want to not drag able the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api, mapactivity

I am trying to set padding to my `Google mMap.setPadding` . It's working but after adding it, another button has come for `move to the current location`

[image]

I dont want this. 
And also I want to map drag feature to be disabled.

Below is my code:

```
int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int padding = (int) (width * 0.20);
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
mMap.setPadding(     0,      270,      0,     430);
mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Comment: add your code trials with errors you getting

Comment: @Dev added code. by these code I set padding. Is there other way to do that? its conflicting with `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do this:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
```